# Aspectratio of AspectRatio() widget is not respected

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**Situation**

- I have a *container* with with a *column* widget as a child. (red widget)
- [Click here for visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeYzN.png)

```
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.redAccent,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Header(),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Pad()
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

- The children of the container are `Header()` (green widget) and `Pad()` (blue widget). Where Pad() has aspect ratio of 1 / 1  (square).

`Header()` widget:

```
    class Header extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.green,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text("CONTAINER WIDGET WITH TEXT"),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

`Pad()` widget:

```
    class Pad extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text("WIDGET WITH 1/1 ASPECT RATIO")
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

**Problem summary**

- If the *container* with *column* is given more horizontal space then vertical, then the 1:1 aspect ratio of Pad() (blue widget) is respected and empty space is left out on both sides of the container (red widget). [Here is a .gif for visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anVrc.gif). So far no issue.
- However, if the container recieves more vertical space then horizontal, then the 1:1 aspect ratio is is not respected and the square changes into rectangle [Here is a visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEHpD.gif)

**Expected / desired behaviour**

- When the container recieves more vertical space then horizontal, the widget with 1:1 aspect ratio should keep it's squared shape. To compensate for the additional space, it should either:

  *a)* Empty space should be kept above and below of the container (same as when more horizontal then vertical space is provided)

  *b)* The Header() widget should expand to compensate for the remaining space

**What I tried so far**

- I suspect that the issue is a direct result of wrapping `Pad()` with the `Expanded()` widget. However, without the *expanded* widget the container with 1:1 aspect ratio would simply overflow, and not shrink.
- If I also wrap the `Pad()` widget with `Expanded()`, then both of the widgets will take equal space (or provided ratio). However, I want the `Header()` to take as little space as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also position your `Pad` in the `Center` of the `Expanded` Widget:

```dart
Expanded(child: Center(child: Pad())),
```

With this solution, your whole UI will expand both horizontally and vertically to fill the whole screen while keeping the `aspectRatio` of 1.

[image]

### Full source code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Header(),
            ),
            Expanded(child: Center(child: Pad())),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Header extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.green,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text("CONTAINER WIDGET WITH TEXT"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Pad extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
        ),
        child: Center(child: Text("WIDGET WITH 1/1 ASPECT RATIO")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is definitelly a better way than what I came up with!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by putting another 1:1 `AspectRatio()` widget inside the original one.

class Pad extends StatelessWidget {

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```